# Programmatically importing works on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: python, plugins, import

So I have a directory tree as follows:

```
pluginlist.py
plugins/
    __init__.py
    plugin1.py
    plugin2.py
    ...
```

And want to concatenate a similarly-named dictionary from each of plugin1, plugin2, etc.

The way I'm doing this is as follows (from pluginlist.py):

```
import os

pluginFolderName = "plugins"
pluginFlag = "##&plugin&##"

commands = {}

os.chdir(os.path.abspath(pluginFolderName))

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if os.path.isfile(file) and os.path.splitext(file)[1] == ".py":
        fileo = open(file, 'r')
        firstline = fileo.readline()
        if firstline == "##&plugin&##\n":
            plugin_mod = __import__("plugins.%s" % os.path.splitext(file)[0])
            import_command = "plugin_commands = plugin_mod.%s" %     os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            exec import_command
            commands = dict(commands.items() + plugin_commands.commands.items())
print commands
```

(The print commands there is for testing purposes)

Running that on Windows gives the proper commands dictionary, but running it on Linux (Ubuntu Server) gives an empty dictionary.

Comment: Can't you use `plugin_commands = getattr(plugin_mod, os.path.splitext(file)[0])` instead of `exec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem! The

```
os.path.isfile(file)
```

test wasn't working because Linux wanted an absolute path to the plugin file. So replacing all instances of file with

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)
```

Seems to fix everything.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if os.path.isfile(file) and ext == ".py":
        with open(file, 'r') as fileo:
            firstline = fileo.readline()
            if firstline.startswith("##&plugin&##"):
                plugin_mod = __import__("plugins.%s" % basename, fromlist = [True])
                plugin_commands = getattr(plugin_mod, basename)
                commands.update(plugin_commands.commands)
```

When you call `__import__('A.B')`, the package `A` is returned.
When you call `__import__('A.B', fromlist = [True])`, the module `B` is returned. It seems to me you want `B`. So on both Windows and Linux, you should need to set `fromlist` to some nonempty list.

Comment: This wasn't the reason it was failing, but it still helped with doing things more idiomatically, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your source code have Windows CRLF line endings? Try adding a `print repr(firstline)` to check that it doesn't end with `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an `else:` branch on the `if` statement which prints a warning if a plugin is missing the identifier

Also, you probably don't care about the line endings, so calling `firstline.strip()` when checking may fix your problem

Finally, pedantically, you can just join `file` to the `pluginFolderName` path instead of using `os.chdir()`

Not tested:

```
pluginFolderName = "plugins"
pluginFlag = "##&plugin&##"

pluginFolderName = os.path.abspath(pluginFolderName)

commands = {}
for file in os.listdir(pluginFolderName):
    # Construct path to file (instead of relying on the cwd)
    file = os.path.join(pluginFolderName, file)

    if os.path.isfile(file) and os.path.splitext(file)[1] == ".py":
        fileo = open(file, 'r')
        firstline = fileo.readline()

        if firstline.strip() == pluginFlag:
            # Strip firstline to ignore trailing whitespace

            plugin_mod = __import__("plugins.%s" % os.path.splitext(file)[0])
            plugin_cmds = getattr(plugin_mod, os.path.splitext(file)[0])
            commands.update(plugin_cmds)
         else:
             print "Warning: %s is missing identifier %r, first line was %r" % (
                 file, PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER, firstline)
```